# Which virtual instruments can be used for sfx?

Tags: sound, sound-libraries, licensing

I'm trying to have a "safe list" of virtual instruments, synths, samplers and anything in between, that can be used for sfx production (mainly for videogame production) but it's often hard to understand what the license permits and what not. I also tried to contact some companies, but they didn't answer (so far) or sounded a bit elusive. Do you know of virtual instruments "safe" for that use? Is an absence of specific indication on the EULA to be assumed as an allowance or not?

EDIT Maybe I can clarify better: I'm talking of the so-called "synchronized use" - so NOT sfx creation for re-sale or re-licensing as a product

Comment: could you add what type of sfx (maybe some examples) you need. this would make it easier to answer... there's a whole world of virtual instrument out there :)

Comment: Do you think it's relevant? At the moment I'm targeting both "magical", abstract sounds, and more normal one. Specifically, atm I'm trying to figure out if:
1- wind noise with Massive is ok
2- magical/sci-fi sound including a sound from sonik synth 2 is ok

Comment: Yes I think it's relevant, your answer shows that actually. Other members here might have the same issue and it makes the question more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb : if its sample-based(*), no, unless you load your own samples.

(*)That's any sampler, rompler, drum machine etc

If its purely synthesis (normally anything with a 'simple' fixed waveform selector, or a draw/generate-your own waveform tool) then youn should be okay.

If its not obvious, consult the EULA, and if thats not enough, contact the developer.

If its really really really not obvious, use analog hardware; that's guaranteed. ;)

Comment: What about analog hardware with samples? Never found a license attached to them, but still...